# OpenEdge dynamic buffers... how do I avoid error 7328? ("unambiguous buffer field/reference for buffers known to a query")

Tags: dynamic, buffer, openedge, progress-4gl

Althogh I've been supporting (and extending) a legacy OE application for 10 years plus, I've never before been forced into the scary world of dynamic buffers...  However, my luck has finally run out.

Let me start by saying I cannot believe how opaque the little OE documentation I could find is... the only Progress guide seems to be in the online documentation for v10.2 (thanks to the contributer to one of the forums for even that snippet.)

Anyway, this should be almost trivial.  Except that it doesn't work;

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hFileBuffer AS WIDGET-HANDLE.
DEFINE VARIABLE hFieldBuffer AS WIDGET-HANDLE.

DEFINE VARIABLE cWhere AS CHARACTER.
DEFINE VARIABLE hQuery AS HANDLE.

CREATE BUFFER hFileBuffer FOR TABLE "_File".
CREATE BUFFER hFieldBuffer FOR TABLE "_Field".

CREATE QUERY hQuery.
hQuery:SET-BUFFERS(hFileBuffer).
hQuery:ADD-BUFFER(hFieldBuffer).

cWhere = SUBSTITUTE(
   "FOR EACH _File " +
   "         NO-LOCK, " +
   "    EACH _Field " +
   "    WHERE _Field.File-recid = _File._File-recid " +
   "          NO-LOCK"
   ).

message cWhere.
pause.

hQuery:Query-PREPARE(cWhere).
hQuery:Query-OPEN().

DELETE OBJECT hQuery. 
DELETE OBJECT hFileBuffer.
DELETE OBJECT hFieldBuffer.

ASSIGN hQuery = ?
       hFileBuffer = ?
       hFieldBuffer = ?.
```

The output from "message" is (after removing redundant spaces):

FOR EACH _File NO-LOCK, EACH _Field WHERE _Field.File-recid = _File._File-recid NO-LOCK

which looks fine to me.

However I then get:

**_Field File-recid must be a quoted constant or an unabbreviated, unambiguous buffer/field reference for buffers known to query . (7328)**

I just cannot see what is ambiguous about "_Field.File-recid" or "_File._File-recid".  Or am I missing something?  (I should add that the equivalent works in good ol'-fashioned static OpenEdge!)

Hoping someone wiser than I can advise,

Allan.

Comment: Just as a comment: there's no need to use SUBSTITUTE there since you're not doing any substitiutions.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues in your dynamic query string:

a) It's RECID(_file) and not _file._file-recid (no _file-recid field on _file)

b) It's _field._file-recid and not _field.file-recid (underscore missing)

```
cWhere = SUBSTITUTE(
   "FOR EACH _File " +
   "         NO-LOCK, " +
   "    EACH _Field " +
   "    WHERE _Field._File-recid = recid(_file)" +
   "          NO-LOCK"
   ).
```

You can enable the display of hidden fields in the Data Dictionary:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mike!  I'll make the changes and let you know what happens!  As an aside, do you have a recommendation for an introduction to Dynamic Buffers (online or otherwise) which won't completely confuse bears of limited brains like myself?  Thanks again, regards Allan.

Comment: There are examples in the k-base (e.g. https://community.progress.com/s/article/P102491).

Comment: Thanks again Mike.  Although I find examples a good way to reinforce material being taught, I'm not convinced that without the theoretical background given in a good tutorial they actually convey understanding.  They promote a "cut and paste" coding technique which means the student includes things because someone else did in an example without either of them ever understanding why.  I'm probably very old-school (well, I'm old anyway!) but I can invariably judge the quality of a training document by simply counting the diagrams.  I just think the mighty PSC did us no favours on this topic!

Answer (score 1):

Just an example on [ABL Dojo](https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=63464bd63fb02369b254a125) to watch your query fly:

```
def var hbfile  as handle no-undo.
def var hbfield as handle no-undo.
def var hq      as handle no-undo.
def var cquery  as char no-undo.

create buffer hbfile for table '_file'.
create buffer hbfield for table '_field'.

create query hq.
hq:set-buffers( hbfile, hbfield ).

cquery  =   substitute( 
                'for each &1 where &1._hidden = false' 
              + ', each &2 where &2._file-recid = recid( &1 )'
              + ' break by &1._file-name',
                hbfile:name,
                hbfield:name
            ).

hq:query-prepare( cquery ).
hq:query-open().
do while hq:get-next():

    if hq:first-of( 1 ) then
        message hbfile::_file-name.
    message ' ' hbfield::_field-name.

end.

finally:
    delete object hq no-error.
    delete object hbfile no-error.
    delete object hbfield no-error.
end finally.
```

A few additional issues with your snippet:

1. buffer handles are regular handles, no need for the meaningless `widget-` prefix
2. when working with dynamic buffers, it really helps to use the `:name` of the dynamic buffer, this allows you to change names without causing the query to fail